What should we keep in mind when using the [reopen-closed] tag?
My closed question #1 on SO:

How to slow down the scroll speed in Microsoft Edge using JavaScript?

The reason it was closed was outright wrong IMO, so I posted on Meta:

My JavaScript question was closed for not being about programming

This was immediately closed for not being suitable for Meta.
So what is the point of the reopen-closed tag?
I read the description of it before posting, and it seemed to be perfect:

A request to have a specific question reopened by the community, often resulting in explanations why it was closed and guidance on improving it.


The problem is not that you're not allowed to use the tag. The problem is that that question isn't asking for input. Also, the fact that you can solve a problem with code, doesn't necessarily make the problem a programming problem. "How do I turn off my PC" isn't a programming problem, but can be answered with code.`

Ironically, this question can be closed for the same reason as the meta question you're complaining about. This isn't you asking for clarification or input. This is just a complaint, complete with incorrect assumptions and, frankly, a sense of entitlement.

@Cerbrus You can call it a complaint all you like, I'm asking what the use of this tag is.

Makyen answered that on your meta question.

You're completely misunderstanding the closure; the closure isn't "do not use this tag", it's "you're using meta wrong", for the reasons Cerbrus already stated. Even though the tag is a request, the request still needs to be answerable, and not just a rant about the closure. See also the end of the tag wiki: "Do not just post a new question stating "this closure was stupid, reopen it" and expect things to go over well. Provide a logical argument why you think the question should be reopened."

@Zoe I provided 56 lines of code logic ;) But seriously, it was closed for being "not programming-related", so I thought posting a block of working code would prove that it is. FWIW, I had no idea there was more to the tag description until you just pointed out you have to click Learn More. Thanks!

A "logical argument" doesn't mean "code". A browser is not a programming tool. The problem is not caused by incorrect code, but seemingly by a setting in your browser. Ergo, it's not a programming question. If you disagree, you need to explain why you think it is a programming question. And again, just because you can hack a solution together with JavaScript, doesn't make it a programming question.

"I thought posting a block of working code would prove that it is." No, see my first comment here.

@Cerbrus No setting has been changed, it is the default setting of Edge. Browser workarounds have been around for how many years.

But it's still a stetting that's responsible for this behavior.

@Cerbrus If you say so, I haven't tried changing any settings so I wouldn't know if it's a setting causing it or not (for example if it is something Microsoft have hardcoded). One user commented that there is a flag, but I haven't tried that because to do so would only fix the problem on my machine and not for all visitors. I was looking for a workaround in JS.

Look, we're trying to explain to you how SO determines if a question is "about programming". It's clear you disagree, in this instance. If you want your disagreement to result in the question being reopened (and staying open), you're going to have to come with a good argument. So far, your argument is just "But I can fix it with code", which, as we stated a few times already, isn't good enough.

I'd suggest you keep the interactions here constructive, Danny.

@DannyBeckett the scroll speed is related to both the OS settings and the browser settings if your intention is to "fix it for all visitors" then your JavaScript solution is something you don't want to do because many users probably don't have that problem (I certainly don't).

@AbdulAzizBarkat This has been explained in the comments on the original question, but it appears to be the default for Edge on Windows 11 23H2. It was observed on a brand new installation of Windows with zero settings changed.

From the deleted Meta question: "I was just looking for a more eloquent solution than introducing a delay." - okay; so why wasn't that in the original question? Or your existing attempt, for that matter? Also: "eloquent" and "elegant" are not the same word.

@KarlKnechtel It was originally in an early comment on the question, which I later deleted and added to the question after it start getting close votes, but that part got rolled back by a mod after revision 8 for being “meta” - so I didn’t re-add it again (although I once again asked for a better solution in my answer, once I was able to post it). I misunderstood the word eloquent, thanks for teaching me something

@KarlKnechtel I even misused the same word in the bit that the mod deleted lol, which you can see on this revision from 9 hours ago. Granted I added a bit more than what was just in the original comment about not wanting to use a delay.

That's why I mentioned it, in fact. If I'd only seen it misused once I'd have brushed it off as a typo or autocorrect issue.

I'm going to make this as clear as I know how.
When you are in a place where content is curated by the community and you seek to appeal a decision that was made about that curation, it is your responsibility to understand the community standards and show some humility.
On the question itself: if the question is "how can I slow down the scroll speed in JavaScript", then it doesn't matter how fast the default scroll speed is, or what browser you're using (unless you have a specific reason to expect that a "standard" JavaScript solution wouldn't work there - which you should know by having already tried one), or how unreasonable you think its defaults are. Therefore, the less you mention these things, the better. It's your responsibility to make it clear that you aren't asking about anything browser-specific, because then people will ask why browser settings don't solve the problem and will therefore consider it off-topic however you tag it. People are sensitive to XY problems because they know from experience that others have them all the time.
Aside from that, we don't need two animated gifs to understand the concept of "fast scroll speed" vs "slow scroll speed". The entire point is not to justify "I need to control the scroll speed in this specific browser for usability reasons" because that's the exact thing that makes the question about the browser (and its ordinary use for browsing the Internet, not as a developer) instead of being about JavaScript.
Even if we take browser settings out of the equation, you are now asking two questions: "how do I control the scroll speed in JavaScript?", and "how do I make the code conditionally run when the browser is Edge?".
On your first Meta post: you started out by being "shocked" that an experienced user could misunderstand your intent, as if reputation should matter in this regard. In reality, clear communication is your responsibility when you post a question on Stack Overflow - which, again, starts with omitting things that could lead the reader astray.
Then you supposed (by "putting it aside" - let's be honest, this is a common rhetorical device) that people "didn't like" your question. Even entertaining the possibility that people are motivated by some kind of bias will rarely go over well - it's not as if you could provide any evidence, anyway. And really, try to imagine how you would feel if you had seen a low-quality question, downvoted it, and then the OP came to Meta to complain with the same phrasing.
It also doesn't help matters that, in the same post where you came to establish that this is about JavaScript and not about Edge, you added another remark about how the Edge scroll speed is "ludicrously fast".
And no, posting the code for your answer here is not helpful. "I can solve the problem by writing code" doesn't establish "the question is about programming" - because "the question" and "the problem" simply aren't that tightly bound."How do I draw a circle in Photoshop?" doesn't become a programming question because someone wrote an AutoHotkey script to do it.
On your post here: your first meta post was closed as "does not appear to seek input and discussion from the community". That's because of the complaints I describe above - both about Edge and about users closing your question. Don't come to Meta with an accusatory tone without expecting severe pushback.
But then, when you receive that message, you are expected to read and understand it. That reason for closing your Meta post was not invented to bother you. It was the sincere impression that your post left behind. Obviously you can, in fact, use the reopen-closed tag to petition for closed questions to be reopened. We, indeed, wouldn't have the tag otherwise.
But you still have to recognize the fact that you're participating in Meta, trying to convince multiple people that policy was misapplied, starting out from a position where you were being told about the policy. It's therefore expected that you start from the assumption that you might not understand policy as well as you think.
As such, writing something like "what is the point of the reopen-closed tag?" very clearly comes across as a rant, and not as an honest question. Frankly, when a Meta post is closed for this reason, immediately making another Meta post to challenge that closure is essentially never going to go well. The entire point of telling you "your post comes across as a rant" is to get you to stop and think about why your post comes across as a rant. If your response is to complain about people having formed that impression, then you have gone exactly wrong, and are doubling down on the mistake.

The original question has now been closed for a 2nd time after being reopened once. I already edited my “please reopen my question” question to make it clearer I’m looking for help to improve it, but it’s too late, that one’s been deleted now too. I will have another attempt at asking a new “please reopen my question” question tomorrow. Tone doesn’t come across well online, and I have a tendency to speak frankly - which I guess can be taken poorly by others - perhaps it is autism lol. My goal is to figure out how to improve the question(s), it isn’t a complaint. I voted to undelete the 2nd one

Reposting a question that got closed is generally a bad idea. The problem isn't in your tone, it's in the assumptions and assertions you're making. Karl covers that in this answer.

Don't underestimate the underlying message in the fact that this post contains an unusually large amount of bold statements. That only happens when you need numerous course corrections.

@Gimby eh... sort of, but my style convention is to use boldface to summarize the post. I try to convey "you need numerous course corrections" via the length of my post and my word choices.

I fear the length might hurt that mission a little, but who cares.

It has been pointed out to me that there is much more to the tag description. I think I did the right thing by reading the description before posting my question:

A request to have a specific question reopened by the community, often resulting in explanations why it was closed and guidance on improving it.

However all of the critical parts are missing until you click Learn more... which then shows:

This tag is to be used for requests to have a question reopened by the community.
Things to consider:

Re-read the help articles on what's on-topic and off-topic for our site and make sure you actually have some ground to stand on.
Read any comments posted on the question. Oftentimes users have already provided you guidance on improving your question - you just need to look. Don't make us repeat things others have already said.
If you haven't done so already, consider editing the question to improve the details, clarify your problem, and remove any fluff that is not relevant to the problem.
See also What can I do when I think my question's not a duplicate?
Do not just post a new question stating "this closure was stupid, reopen it" and expect things to go over well. Provide a logical argument why you think the question should be reopened.


I had no idea there was more text hiding. I found this to be very helpful, so thanks @Zoe!
